# implement android beam in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nfc

I'm develop cross-platform mobile application that use NFC. I already check the xamarin android beam [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/AndroidBeamDemo/). Now i'm trying implement the same sample using xamarin forms so i'm using dependency service to call the function from android project. I try to make simple message that pass from device to another but it didn't work. The problem is the implementation of NfcAdapter.IOnNdefPushCompleteCallback

PhoneBeam.cs

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using MyApp.Droid;
using Android.Nfc;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PhoneBeam))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class PhoneBeam : Activity, NfcAdapter.ICreateNdefMessageCallback, NfcAdapter.IOnNdefPushCompleteCallback, iBeam
    {

        private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;

        public void Beam()
        {


            nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.GetDefaultAdapter(MainActivity.Instance);

            nfcAdapter.SetNdefPushMessageCallback(this, MainActivity.Instance);
            nfcAdapter.SetOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(this, MainActivity.Instance);

        }

        public NdefMessage CreateNdefMessage(NfcEvent evt)
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            var text = ("Beam me up!\n\n" + "Beam : " +
                time.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
            NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(
                new NdefRecord[]{ CreateMimeRecord (
            "application/com.example.android.beam",
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (text)) });

            return msg;
        }

        public NdefRecord CreateMimeRecord(String mimeType, byte[] payload)
        {
            byte[] mimeBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mimeType);
            NdefRecord mimeRecord = new NdefRecord(
                NdefRecord.TnfMimeMedia, mimeBytes, new byte[0], payload);
            return mimeRecord;
        }

    }

}
```

It says 'PhoneBeam does not implement interface member NfcAdapter.IOnNdefPushCompleteCallback.OnNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent)'. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class implements [IOnNdefPushCompleteCallback](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Nfc.NfcAdapter+IOnNdefPushCompleteCallback/), which has a public method `OnNdefPushComplete` that must be implemented in order to satisfy the Interface.